# Solving IVP by Laplace transform

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm trying to solve an IVP with non-constant coefficients
$$ y'' + 3ty' - 6y = 1, \quad y(0) = 0, \; y'(0) = 0 $$

Taking the Laplace yields
$$ s^2Y + 3(Y + sY') - 6Y = \frac{1}{s}$$
$$ Y' + \left(\frac{s}{3} - \frac{1}{s}\right)Y = \frac{1}{3s^2}$$

The integrating factor is
$$ \mu(s) = \exp\left(\frac{s^2}{6} -\ln s\right) = \frac{1}{s}e^{\frac{s^2}{6}}$$

Thus
$$ \frac{d}{ds}\left( \frac{1}{s}e^{\frac{s^2}{6}}Y \right) = \frac{1}{3s^3}e^{\frac{s^2}{6}}$$

This where I'm stuck because I'm pretty sure the integral on the RHS is non-elementary.

I do know that the solution supposed to be $y = t^2/2$ and $Y = 1/s^3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant $y'' + 3 t y' - 6 y = 1$.  Then you should get
$$ s^2 Y(s) - 9 Y(s) - 3 s Y'(s) = \dfrac{1}{s}$$

Comment: That's right, I forgot the negative sign!